# Can't play barre chords - crooked finger

Tags: guitar, chords, physical-limitations

Okay so, I have been practicing barre chords for the last some 8 months, I can play them but I'm not getting faster.

Then, I realised that I cannot physically keep my ring and pinky together like I can in my right hand.  I do have a slightly crooked ring finger, but I'm not sure it's the culprit, please help! I love the guitar!

Pic of my left hand, notice how ring bends towards middle and pinky seems to be going away!:
[image: Pic of my left hand, notice how ring bends towards middle and pinky seems to be going away]

This is what I'm trying to achieve, I can only do it on my right hand:
[image: This is what I'm trying to achieve, I can only do it on my right hand]

Notice slightly crooked ring finger:
[image: Notice slightly crooked ring finger]

Comment: Which shape barre chords are effected?

Comment: You do not have to use your pinky when playing a major barre chord.  I generally don't (though I do put it to use in 7th and 9th chords.)

Comment: Similarly to the previous comments, I'd like to ask why you want to have those fingers together. I've been looking at how I do various chords all over the neck, and I don't see anywhere I must have them touching. Is there a specific chord giving you trouble?

Comment: All the f shapes are affected

Comment: @DoktorMayhem its the F-shape as there is always so much space between my ring and pinky,  the only to mitigate it is to place the bar middle and ring, then slightly bend my hand while my ring is ON the fretboard to force the pinky next to it ( not necessarily touching it close to stay and ring out on the same fret)

Answer (score 2):

I've got a similarly slightly crooked middle finger on my left hand.  (And I remember when it happened - the doctor said it wasn't broken and let it be, but I knew it was!).   It's quite useful actually, I can stretch an octave on keyboard 1 - 3 much easier than with my RH!

It really makes no difference on guitar barre chords.  Have you got a guitar teacher?  You might need showing some technique.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your ring and pinky fingers loosely with tape or stretchable medical warpping material, so the they will stay together when barring a Am6, Am7 at the fifth fret or a C at the third fret, or a G barred at the third fret. Check to see if the fingers can move far enough apart to make a G7 at the third fret usig your pinky on the second string.